# File Not Found When Working with PyCharm but its okay when working jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I am trying to importing a file with pandas in python. Both the file and python script are in same directory. But when I am trying to open that file in pycharm, after executing that script I am getting an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

But When I am running that same command in jupyter notebook, the file opens just fine.
This is the code I am using to open file:

```
hos = "Hospital Lists.xlsx"
hospital = pd.read_excel(hos, sheet_name=0)
```

> Note That: Both the files and script are in same directory

To Solving this problem I have to use absolute path in pycharm:

```
hos = "F:\My Coding\Python\Hospital Lists.xlsx"
hospital = pd.read_excel(hos, sheet_name=0)
```

> This solves the problem

But why relative path working in jupyter but not in pycharm? This is my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Because I was running the streamlit. But I wasn't running the powershell from the script folder. That is why I was facing the file not found error. But in the case of jupyter, I was running it from the script folder. If I run the powershell from the script folder then relative path is working.

Answer (score 1):

Those two environments clearly use a different working directory. You can add

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

to your code to see those working directories when you run the script from PyCharm or Jupyter.

Comment: I did run the code that you have shared in both pycharm and jupyter. And both of them returning the same directory

Comment: @NahidujjamanHridoy And are you sure this is the line where the error occurs? Can you posst the full code?

Comment: I think I got the problem. When I run the code using streamlit that is when the problem occurs. I think streamlit server needs to know the absolute path. It does not understand the relative path.